# What is the probability that at least one of the selected students is not right handed?

Tags: probability

The problem:
A survey found that about 90% of the junior class is right handed. If 2 juniors are chosen at random out of 100 juniors, what is the probability that at least one of them is not right handed?

I know that one possible way to approach this problem is to find
P(at least one is right handed) and then compute 1-P(at least one is right handed) but what is an alternative way to do it if you use the fact that 10% of the population are not right handed?

Comment: I don't understand your method.  Can you write out the calculation you intend?

Comment: I don't see why this is downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Select two jurors and let $X_1, X_2$ be indicators that each is left-handed.   Values of one indicate that they are, and values of zero indicate that they are not.

The event that at least one is not right-handed is : $\{X_1{+}X_2{\geq}1\}$.

We are told that $\mathsf P(X_\star=0)=0.9~,~\mathsf P(X_\star=1)=0.1$ for each juror and  *independence is assumed.*

Then by complements:

$$\mathsf P(X_1{+}X_2{\geq}1)~{=~1-\mathsf P(X_1{+}X_2{=}0)\\=~1-\mathsf P(X_1{=}0)\,\mathsf P(X_2{=}0)}$$

Alternatively, by the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion:

$$\mathsf P(X_1{+}X_2{\geq} 1) ~{=~ \mathsf P(X_1{=}1)+\mathsf P(X_2{=}1)-\mathsf P(X_1{=}1,X_2{=}1)\\=~ \mathsf P(X_1{=}1)+\mathsf P(X_2{=}1)-\mathsf P(X_1{=}1)~\mathsf P(X_2{=}1) }$$

Or by Total Probability

$$\mathsf P(X_1+X_2\geq 1) ~{=~ \mathsf P(X_1{=}1,~X_1{+}X_2{\geq}1)+\mathsf P(X_1{=}0,X_1{+}X_2{\geq}1) \\=~\mathsf P(X_1{=}1)~\mathsf P(X_2{\geq}0)+\mathsf P(X_1{=}0)~\mathsf P(X_2\geq 1)}$$

And such like.

---

Can you modify this for the case where independence is not assumed?

Comment: +1. To clarify the complements step: The probability that at least one of the two chosen juniors is not right handed is the same as $1$ minus the probability that both are right handed.

Answer (score 0):

At least one of them is not right ended --

Is the opposite of  (both of them are right handed)

Both of them right handed = 90% * 90% = 81%.

Opposite of that is 19%.

Probability that at least one of them is not right handed is 19%.